# TomCat error page after deployment

Tags: java, tomcat

I made a .war file that prints strings to the console when I run in cmd

```
java -jar print.war
```

However, when I deploy this .war file to tomcat 8 by copying the file into the webapps folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps
```

I get this error whenever I go to http://localhost:8080/print

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 19 14:36:59 CST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Does that mean my deployment failed?  Or is there something wrong with my .war file?

Thanks.

Comment: Without any code it's a bit difficult to tell but I question that you're running a war file on the command line.  Are you using a JSP or servlets or are you just creating a main() method?

Comment: I'm just creating a main() method.  Thanks.

Comment: does your `war` file includes `web.xml` or `javax` annotations ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to process http request you need to specify a class that extends `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` and provide a deployment descriptor to let your servlet container know where should it delegate specific request.

If those terms are new to you, visit: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/ for more informations.